# jquery function won't use input variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, fadein, fadeout

So I have a button on a div that should make the corresponding page fade out when clicked and another page fade in (page2, which is set to display:none). My script won't work though. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
<div>
    <div id="page1">
       <button onclick="fade(page1,page2)"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fade(out_ID, in_ID){
    $("#"+out_ID).fadeOut(1000);
    $("#"+in_ID).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The parameters should be strings. `onclick="fade('page1', 'page2')"`

Comment: `$("#undefined")` likely doesn't exist. And you should be getting an error due to page1 doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks joe! that worked :) need to pay more attention to detail

Comment: No problem! It's easy to make silly mistakes :) Even the best do from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Just need to add quotes for the parameters.

```
<button onclick="fade('page1','page2')"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite to use jquery to the full and remove inline javascript:

```
<div>
    <div id="page1">
       <button id="myButton"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // wait for page to load
    $(function () {
      $('#myButton').click(function(){
         fade($('#page1'), $('#page2'));
      });
    });

    function fade(out_ID, in_ID){
        out_ID.fadeOut(1000);
        in_ID.delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }
</script>
```

that should sort you out.